# Why it's alert no defination about ${index} value in For IN express of Robotframework

Tags: for-loop, robotframework

Define a list which contian serveral name to check, If found 'lvbu' string, then jump out the LOOP body. But the express seems not suit for robotframwork, Could tell me why it's notice name'liubei
is not define about the variable ${index}
Code:

```
Exit For Loop
@{items}    Create List    liubei    zhangfei    guanyu    lvbu    zhaoyun    machao
FOR    ${index}    IN    @{items}
    Run Keyword If    ${index}==lvbu    Exit For Loop
END
```

Trace info:

20211224 23:34:12.775 : TRACE : Arguments: [ 'liubei' | 'zhangfei' | 'guanyu' | 'lvbu' | 'zhaoyun' | 'machao' ]

20211224 23:34:12.775 : TRACE : Return: ['liubei', 'zhangfei', 'guanyu', 'lvbu', 'zhaoyun', 'machao']

20211224 23:34:12.776 :  INFO : @{items} = [ liubei | zhangfei | guanyu | lvbu | zhaoyun | machao ]

20211224 23:34:12.779 : TRACE : Arguments: [ 'liubei==lvbu' | 'Exit For Loop' ]

20211224 23:34:12.785 :  FAIL : Evaluating expression 'liubei==lvbu' failed: NameError: name 'liubei' is not defined nor importable as module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression must be a valid python expression after robot substitutes variables. Like the error shows, the expression being evaluated becomes `liubei == lvbu`. That means that *python* (not robot) must have a variable named `liubei` and another one named `lvbu`.

If you are trying to compare strings, you must properly quote them. For example, this will work if you know `${index}` itself doesn't have any quote characters:

```
Run Keyword If  '${index}' == 'lvbu'  Exit For Loop
```

Robot has a special syntax for variables used in expressions. If you leave off the curly braces, robot will create the python variable for you, which avoids the problem of having to know if the variable has quotes in it or not.

```
Run Keyword If  $index == 'lvbu'  Exit For Loop
```

For more information see the section titled [Evaluating expressions](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions) in the documentation for the BuiltIn library.

Comment: There is another question, Code like below. just like you said robot need to substitute the   ${index}  to Python variable. If I set variable ${index} value equal 1 which also can be treated as a string in robot.  why there the express is work?     ...........
    ${index}    Set Variable    1
    Should Be True    ${index}==1

Comment: Yes, after add quote on ${index} and lvbu , it's work, Thank you @Bryan Oakley  very much!  I will carefull read that link.